# Populate select option from previous select in Laravel

Tags: javascript, php, laravel

I have this select option and I am trying to populate Submenus which is another select option from the other select option mainmenu in `laravel` depending on the selection from MainMenu:

```
<div class="form-row">
      <div class="form-group col-md-4">
        <label for="inputState">Main Menu</label>
        <select id="inputState" name="mainmenu" class="form-control">
          <option selected>Choose...</option>
          @foreach ($mainmenus as $mainmenu)
          <option>{{$mainmenu->Title}}</option>  
          @endforeach   
        </select>
      </div>
```

I get the values in to polulate this mainmenu option from the query:

```
$mainmenus = DB::connection("mysql2")->table("MainMenu")->get();
```

I get the submenu with the following query:

```
 $submenu = DB::connection("mysql2")->table('applicationsubmenu')
            ->join('applicationmenu', 'applicationmenu.Id', '=', 'applicationsubmenu.ApplicationMenuId')
            ->select('applicationsubmenu.*')
            ->where('applicationmenu.MainMenuId', '=', $main_menu_id)
            ->get();
```

Can someone help me? How can I do this dynamically?Thanks in advance,I really appreciate!

Comment: First of, in html when setting the select option, you need to include the actual value you need to pick `<option value="{{$mainmenu->id}}>{{$mainmenu->title</option>"`

Comment: this is not a problem but okay then what,@AntonyMN

Comment: Do you want to connect to the backend so as to retrieve the submenus once you have selected the main menu id?

Comment: @AntonyMN that is what I am trying to do...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At the bottom of the page, I would implement a Js function as follows

```
<script>
 $(document).ready(function(){
  $('#inputState').change(function(){
    var main_menu_id = $('#inputState').val();
    axios.post('/submenus', {
       main_menu_id: main_menu_id
     }).then((r)=>{
      var submenus = r.data.submenus;
      for(var i=0; i<submenus.length; i++){
      $('#submenu').append('<option>'+submenus[i].title+'</option>');
    }
     });
  });
 });
</script>
```

Define the link in the web.php file

```
<?php
  ...
  Route::get('/submenus','SubmenuController@getsubmenus');
?>
```

Now, on the controller,

```
<?php
namespace ...;
use Illuminate\Http\Request; 
use Response;
use DB;

public function getsubmenus(Request $request){
   return Response([
      'submenu' => DB::connection("mysql2")->table('applicationsubmenu')
        ->join('applicationmenu', 'applicationmenu.Id', '=', 
       'applicationsubmenu.ApplicationMenuId')
        ->select('applicationsubmenu.*')
        ->where('applicationmenu.MainMenuId', '=', $request->main_menu_id)
        ->get(),
    ]);
} 
?>
```

Comment: okay I get your idea but how do I populate this: `<div class="form-row">
      <div class="form-group col-md-4">
        <label for="inputState">SubMenu</label>
        <select id="inputState" class="form-control">
          <option selected>Choose...</option>
          <option>some</option>  
        </select>
      </div>`

Comment: If I do this :`@foreach ($submenu as $s)
          <option>{{$s->Title}}</option>  
          @endforeach` it returns `{"submenu":[]}`

Comment: cmon dont leave me like this

Comment: Check the JS function I have added the append function looking through each element in the array that was returned by the axios.

Comment: how do I do that?I have made some modifications `axios.post('/', {` and  `Route::get('/','TicketController@getSubmenus');` however this returns an empty array

Comment: I have added this in the JS function
`for(var i=0; i<submenus.length; i++){
      $('#submenu').append('<option>'+submenus[i].title+'</option>');
    }`

Comment: I need this to refer to the same page

Comment: yes, It is in the same script that is running the axios. Once you have the submenus, the you loop each and append it to the select whose Id is submenu, just check the scripts in the answer

Comment: the output is still the same `{"submenu":[]}`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/171717/discussion-between-antonymn-and-randomuser).